# Correct routing, but incomplete map matching with own Valhalla server

Tags: server, configuration, map-matching, valhalla

I installed Valhalla from [gis-ops docker](https://github.com/gis-ops/docker-valhalla) image (version 3.3.0 on Doker Hub, default options, latest Europe data from Geofabrik.de).  Routing seems to work fine, however map matching isn’t quite as efficient as expected.

Here is an example :

[image: map matching example]

The blue line represents the trip obtained either by routing on this server from the first and last point of the trip, or the trip obtained by map matching the points on valhalla1.openstreetmap.de (it successfully provides exactly the same route).

The red lines, on the other hand, represents the trip and alternates paths obtained by map matching the points on our instance, with the *exact same request* as above.

We figured mainly highways seems to be missed, but playing with costing options didn’t seem to help.

Any clue what’s going on ?

Here is an example of query (again we tried to play with options without success) :

```
 '{
  "shape": [{"lon": 19.73391, "lat": 47.586327, "type": "break"}, {"lon": 19.73391, "lat": 47.586327, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.735006, "lat": 47.58685, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.742891, "lat": 47.585697, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.744741, "lat": 47.584778, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.745676, "lat": 47.584846, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.749643, "lat": 47.59676, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.733253, "lat": 47.6177, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.728012, "lat": 47.641727, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.723392, "lat": 47.661102, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.715866, "lat": 47.67743, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.70214, "lat": 47.686848, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.666155, "lat": 47.68412, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.634537, "lat": 47.671715, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.601048, "lat": 47.661808, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.56681, "lat": 47.653095, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.53271, "lat": 47.644253, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.49671, "lat": 47.64092, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.463673, "lat": 47.63191, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.42855, "lat": 47.62535, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.39938, "lat": 47.61296, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.36559, "lat": 47.616962, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.32878, "lat": 47.614403, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.320152, "lat": 47.59814, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.323374, "lat": 47.57763, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.315826, "lat": 47.55528, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.304335, "lat": 47.530872, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.29696, "lat": 47.506966, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.312492, "lat": 47.48683, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.33209, "lat": 47.466526, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.332298, "lat": 47.441418, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.316149, "lat": 47.418728, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.310757, "lat": 47.400177, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.310757, "lat": 47.400177, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.30901, "lat": 47.399147, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.305096, "lat": 47.396873, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.30508, "lat": 47.39686, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.304441, "lat": 47.396282, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.297253, "lat": 47.389996, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.294447, "lat": 47.38908, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.292248, "lat": 47.38845, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.290688, "lat": 47.387978, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.284801, "lat": 47.3854, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.28388, "lat": 47.38498, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.283344, "lat": 47.384712, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.268633, "lat": 47.378983, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.236057, "lat": 47.36787, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.204494, "lat": 47.35464, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.186363, "lat": 47.37286, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.168858, "lat": 47.39459, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.154709, "lat": 47.417244, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.161224, "lat": 47.42257, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.161005, "lat": 47.42238, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.161005, "lat": 47.42238, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.161005, "lat": 47.42238, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.161005, "lat": 47.42238, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.161005, "lat": 47.42238, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.161005, "lat": 47.42238, "type": "via"}, {"lon": 19.161005, "lat": 47.42238, "type": "break"}],
  "costing": "auto",
  "shape_match": "map_snap",
  "speed": "max_speed",
  "trace_options.gps_accuracy": 50,
  "trace_options.breakage_distance": 100,
  "linear_references": true
}'
```

Edit : I hadn’t carefully read the paragraph about the docker image options.  Maybe it would help to set one or several of `build_elevation`, `build_admins`, `build_time_zones` and `build_transit`.